# Is this last statement a convergence in probability, why does this converse holds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, convergence-divergence

[image]

[Theorem 7.6](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_7_almost_sure_convergence.php)

I can see why does almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, and I don't see why does this converse also holds.

Thank you for any help

**Thank you all for the posts, here it does not say anything about the nested sequence, so I did not think about it this way. If increasing sequence is provided, is that sufficient prove this solely by the continuity of probability?**

Comment: You have convergence in probability if $P(|X_m-X|<\epsilon)\to1$. What you have here is stronger since the event $A_m$ is not $\{|X_m-X|<\epsilon\}$ but rather $\{|X_n-X|<\epsilon\text{ for all }n\geq m\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just provides more details to [geetha290krm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064504/geetha290krm)'s answer.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Note that $A_{\varepsilon,m}=\cap_{n\geq m}\{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}$ and $A_{\varepsilon,m}\subseteq A_{\varepsilon ,m+1}$. Then define $A_\varepsilon:=\cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}A_{\varepsilon,m}$ (it is a monotone class; this also implies $P(A_\varepsilon)=\lim_mP(A_{\varepsilon,m})$ by measure continuity). We have
$$A_\varepsilon=\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n\geq m}\{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}$$
Now note that this means that if $\omega \in A_\varepsilon$, then there exists $m$ s.t. $\forall n\geq m$, $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|<\varepsilon$. We suppose $P(A_\varepsilon)=1$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. Now consider
$$A:=\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}A_{1/k}$$
Then $A=\{\lim_n X_n=X\}$. So by De Morgan's laws and measure monotonicity, $P(A^c)\leq \sum_kP(A_{1/k}^c)=0$. So $P(A)=1$ and we conclude that $X_n\to X$ $P$-a.s.

$(\Rightarrow)$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $A\subseteq A_\varepsilon$, so $1=P(A)\leq P(A_\varepsilon)=1$ necessarily.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I can see you presume it is an increasing sequence and then with some technique. I am wondering if an increasing sequence is allowed, is it by continuity of probability sufficient to prove the converse because it is pretty much taken out the limit.

Comment: @LJNG no assumption is made except for the theorem's premises. I just laid out all the [properties of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_below) that can be used to prove the theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$(A_m)$ is an increasing sequence.  So $\lim P(A_m)=P(A)$ where $A =\bigcup_m A_m =\{|X_n-X| <\epsilon \, \, \text {for all }\, n \,\,\text {sufficiently large}\}$. We can let $\epsilon \to 0$ through a sequence and conclude that $1=P(A)=P(X_n \to X)$.